# How to send back a lot of images from node.js to client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I want to send 324 158x158 png images to client side from node.js. Then from client side I want to pick any of those images, and draw it on a canvas in the most efficient way. Assume I can't lazy load, and need to transfer them all together.

If it helps, they can be sent as Uint8ClampedArray arrays instead of image format.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: You could send them as data-urls. Or is your question intended on how to actually load the images with NodeJS?

Comment: I figured it out, I combined them into 1 super large image in node.js, then send it back, then use div background positioning offset to pick which one to draw.